# Bootstrap - prevent text size to affect the next div position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days. What I mean is that I have the below code which is a horizontal card where the image is on the left and text goes to the right.

```css
    .title {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <!-- Products -->
                <li class="card shadow-none card-fluid mb-3 mb-md-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                            <img class="img-fluid rounded"
                                src="{% img src %}"
                                alt="Image Description">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="card-header py-md-0 py-lg-0 py-xl-0 pl-0 pr-0">
                                <h6 class="h5 mb-2 title">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
                                    adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
                                    sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                                    ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
                                    pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede
                                    justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim
                                    justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam
                                    dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
                                    dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend
                                    tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend
                                    ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,
                                </h6>
                                <p class="font-size-1">
                                    Text of 20 characters.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body p-0 px-0 py-md-0 py-lg-0 py-xl-0 body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-8 text-left">
                                        <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                                            <span class="static-rating static-rating-sm d-block mr-2">
                                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                        <span class="d-inline-block">
                                            <h6 class="mt-0 mb-2">4.95/5
                                                <small class="text-white-70">(1.5k+ review-uri)</small>
                                            </h6>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- End Products -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see from above, the card has two `divs`. One is for the header where I display the big text and the other, I use it for the other information as reviews.

However, the second div - `card-body` class - is pushed down when the text within `h6` class is bigger and is where as it should when is less text.

In order to this, I was thinking to limit and to overflow the text and limit to display maximum of only two rows. To limit this, I used the following CSS properties:

The above works fine but the second `div` still is being affected even by this. How can I block/prevent the second `div` from being pushed down in this situation? Any tips would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
.card-header {
height:100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

this will help you

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Well, apart from the height the others properties were already being used in the `title` class.

Comment: you need to use it with card-header